# How to Remove Quotes in a list in Python

Tags: python

I want to remove the quotes from the variable average.
Here is my code:

```
list_1 = ['LIST: ']
list_2 = [['Mary Smith', 132, 'Jean Jones', 156, 'Karen Karter', 167]]
list_3 = ['Mary Smith', 132, 'Jean Jones', 156, 'Karen Karter', 167]
combine = (str(list_1)[2:-2]) + (str(list_2)[1:-1])
print(combine)
new_list = input("Name to add to the list: ")
average = input("Average: ")
list_3.append(new_list)
list_3.append(average) 
print(f"UPDATED LIST: {list_3}")
print("There are now {0} items".format(len(list_3)), "in  the list")
```

Here is what I want to come out:

```
LIST: ['Mary Smith', 132, 'Jean Jones', 156, 'Karen Karter', 167]
Name to add to the list: Ann Kert
Average: 189
UPDATED LIST: ['Mary Smith', 132, 'Jean Jones', 156, 'Karen Karter', 167, 'Ann Kert', 189]
There are now 8 items in  the list
```

But here is what I got:

```
LIST: ['Mary Smith', 132, 'Jean Jones', 156, 'Karen Karter', 167]
Name to add to the list: Ann Kert
Average: 189
UPDATED LIST: ['Mary Smith', 132, 'Jean Jones', 156, 'Karen Karter', 167, 'Ann Kert', '189']
There are now 8 items in  the list
```

If you don't see the difference then the difference is the 189 needs to have no qoutes but the thing that I got is '189'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! With `input` you got a string value '189'. And I suppose that you want integer value, e.g. `int('189')` - right?

Comment: `combine = (str(list_1)[2:-2]) + (str(list_2)[1:-1])` this is one of the weirdest Python lines I saw. Probably you wanted `print('LIST:', list_2[0])` or `print('LIST:', list_3)`

Answer (score 3):

Try type casting the string into int.

```
average = int(input("Average: "))
```